# how to SUM in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

*`PRIJEM`: The income table contains data about the goods by the documents in detail for the entire period*

```
ICO CHAR(8)
DOKLAD CHAR(16)
DATUM DATETIME
PrijemEur Money
```

*`VYDAJ`:Table of expense / sales / includes data on the sale of goods by the documents in detail for the whole period*

```
ICO CHAR(8)
DOKLAD CHAR(16)
DATUM DATETIME
VydajEur Money
```

*`ORG`: dial all customers with integration into different districts.*

```
ICO CHAR(8)
NAZOV VARCHAR
OKRES char(10)
```

My question is: I would like the complete List the sum of income and expenditure for each `ICO` contained 
Tables movements of the form (customer turnover):

```
ICO, name, PrijemEur, VydajEur    """???
```

Comment: did you try anything at all? what contents do the tables have? what is the result you got, what is the result you want

Comment: what do you mean by sum? do you want to see all your tables fields in a query?

Comment: http://s17.postimg.org/ndodnidz3/image.png

Comment: Are you trying to `SELECT` and additional column containing `PrijemEur` **minus** `VydajEur`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.ICO, o.NAZOV as name, SUM(p.PrijemEur), SUM(v.VydajEur) 
FROM ORG o 
LEFT JOIN PRIJEM p ON(p.ICO = o.ICO) 
LEFT JOIN VYDAJ v ON(v.ICO = o.ICO)
GROUP BY o.ICO, o.NAZOV
```

should work (not tested)

Comment: super :) a when i write List any records sorted and summarized by the date on which the
receive and not expense (on a given day are bought, but sold by)
Date PrijemEur??